# Saving Rails model as JSON

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, json, controller, angularjs

This seems like a question that would have already been asked, but I couldn't find quite what I was looking for, so I'll just go ahead and ask.

I'm trying to use angular.js to make an instant search function on my site. I want users to be able to search through Posts (by title and content, ideally) instantaneously, so after hearing about [angular's ability to do this](http://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_04), I gave it a shot.

I have this going on in my posts.js.coffee file:

```
@PostListCtrl = ($scope, $http) ->
  $http.get("posts.json").success (data) ->
    $scope.posts = data
```

And this going on in the JSON doc it references (just to make sure it was working -- which it is).

```
data =
    [
    name: "Blog ex"
    content: "This is my example post."
    ,
    name: "Test posting"
    content: "A different ex post"
    ,
    name: "Test3"
    content: "This has some unusual, unique vocabulary."
    ]
```

Now all I have left to do is get Rails to save an object (with name/content attributes) in the above JSON file each time a new Post is created, so that the search actually runs through meaningful data. I'm new to Rails/JSON/computer stuff and don't have a clue how to do this. I'm guessing it's in the posts controller, maybe in one of those respond_to blocks, but if anyone could point me to the right way to do this, I'd appreciate it.

Comment: you should reconsider what you are doing... essentially you want to load all your blog content data into a page every time user comes to it so they can search locally. You can search very quickly leaving the data on server and using AJAX. Look at using an autocomplete widget such as jQueryUI http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#remote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all you want is an instant search, or autocomplete functionality, you should not use Angular.js or any other JS MVC frameworks. Instead, consider using jQuery as @charliefl suggested, it's easy. A simple Ajax call will do it.

JS MVC frameworks are heavy, and you need to design the architecture from the bottom to suit them. Not worthy for such a single functionality.

To make this function work in jQuery, basically:

1. Listen the event on search box, say typing one or more characters
2. Catch the characters and use jQuery Ajax to send a POST request to a method in PostsController in Rails, say "search"
3. Make this method respond to JSON.
4. Update DOM according to server response.

Comment: K. Message taken. I'll look into your and charliefl's suggestions. Thanks!